# Why is my CSS grid and flexbox of images showing me blank white space when I view my webpage on a phone or Safari?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am doing a 180-day webpage challenge on https://taniaswebpages.com, and website 9 for some reason is supposed to display 8 images in a grid. On my Mac (Chrome) it works perfectly fine but for some reason on my phone, I am getting images with white space underneath, as well as Safari on Mac. How can I fix this?? I have attached an image that shows the issue I am dealing with. If someone could please help me solve this issue I would greatly appreciate it.

I have used CSS grid techniques and flexbox to display my images in a grid.

[Grid display on my iphone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jY3Zc.jpg)

MY HTML:

```
<! DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="taniaWebsite7.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body class="mainpage8">
    <div class="containerr">
      <h1 class="heading">New Zealand 2018 <span> Image Gallery</span></h1>
      <div class="gallery">
        <div class="gallery-item"><img class="gallery-image" src="1.png" alt="one" /></div>
        <div class="gallery-item"><img class="gallery-image" src="2.png" alt="two" /></div>
        <div class="gallery-item"><img class="gallery-image" src="3.png" alt="three" /></div>
        <div class="gallery-item"><img class="gallery-image" src="4.png" alt="four" /></div>
        <div class="gallery-item"><img class="gallery-image" src="5.png" alt="five" /></div>
        <div class="gallery-item"><img class="gallery-image" src="6.png" alt="six" /></div>
        <div class="gallery-item"><img class="gallery-image" src="7.png" alt="seven" /></div>
        <div class="gallery-item"><img class="gallery-image" src="8.png" alt="eight" /></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.heading {
  font-family: oswald;
  font-size: 4rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3.5rem 0;
  color:lightblue;
}

.heading span {
  display: block;
}

.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* Compensate for excess margin on outer gallery flex items */
  margin: -1rem -1rem;
}

.gallery-item {
  flex: 1 0 24rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  box-shadow: 0.3rem 0.4rem 0.4rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.gallery-image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  object-fit: cover;
  transition: transform 400ms ease-out;
}

.gallery-image:hover {
  transform: scale(1.15);
}

@supports (display: grid) {
  .gallery {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(24rem, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 2rem;
  }
  .gallery,
  .gallery-item {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove height from .gallery-item that contains the image it will collapse to the size of the image inside. Images maintain their ratio unless given a height but I do not suggest that because it will heavily distort the image.

Here is a helpful article about image ratios: https://designshack.net/articles/layouts/understanding-and-working-with-aspect-ratio/

Comment: currently my height is set to 50%, if I change it to 100% the images  get distorted and the page glitches a bit.

Comment: One should never set height for an image otherwise you get mixed results because it is not responsive. If you remove the .gallery-item height it should collapse to the height of the image inside. The issue is because height is declared on the parent container that holds the image.

Comment: If I set the height to lets say 40px, the preview of my webpage in Brackets gives me smaller images, but then again it doesn't update in browser.

Comment: my suggestion was to NOT set a height for the div that contains the image or the image itself. Just remove it from .gallery-item completely.